# Rails: uninitialized constant class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this problem:

> uninitialized constant QuestionsController::Question

```
def index
    @Question
    @preguntas = Question.all
    @project_id = request.original_url.split('.').last
    set_current_project(@project_id)
    if(@project_id.include? "http")
```

On my `QuestionController` randomly after changing nothing from my application, any idea what may be causing it? here's the complete `.rb` file:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user
before_action :require_project
before_action :require_user, except: [:new, :create]
before_action :current_project, only: [:index]
def index
    @preguntas = Question.all
    @project_id = request.original_url.split('.').last
    set_current_project(@project_id)
if(@project_id.include? "http")
@project_id = "0"
end
    if(@project_id != "0")
        @proyecto = Project.find(@project_id)
    end 
end

def show
  @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @pregunta = Question.new
end

def create
  @pregunta = Question.new(pregunta_params)
  if @pregunta.save
     redirect_to @pregunta
  else
     render 'new'
  end
end
 def edit
     @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
  @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
  if @pregunta.update(pregunta_params)
    redirect_to @pregunta
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end


 def destroy
    @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
    @pregunta.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Se ha borrado la pregunta"
    redirect_to questions_path
end 


def require_same_user 
    set_project
    if current_user != @project.user && !@current_user.admin?
        flash[:danger] = "Solo puedes editar tus artículos"
        redirect_to root_path
    end 
end 

def require_project
    if current_user.projects.count <1 && !current_user.admin?
        redirect_to root_path
    end 
end 

private
    def pregunta_params
        params.require(:question).permit(:question, :value, :phase, :area, :input)
    end
```

end

Comment: Well, is there a class `Question`?

Comment: Sorry it is my first time posting something here, turns out question.rb was missing from the models folder for some reason, restoring the files to an earlier state solved the problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the `Question` model is defined in a file named `app/models/question.rb` like this:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  # methods...
end
```

Comment: Thank you, after adding the file question.rb the problem was fixed :)

Comment: Technically, `Question` class has to be _somewhere_. But yes, from the usage, it does look like a model.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree. But it is much easier to put it at a place where Rails autoloading finds it (inside the app folder for example) instead of just _somewhere_ (what might need to require it manually).

Comment: @spickermann: no-no, I meant that it could just as well reside in `app/presenters` or something (if it were a presenter, that is).